# How to store local storage data using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have seen many examples for fetching the already stored data but didn't get any example for fetching the stored values.

Comment: check below answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960598/accessing-localstorage-in-protractor-test-for-angularjs-application

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I already go through to this link but there is no content regarding the storing of the values using protractor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access localStorage through browser.executeScript() this way:

**Get value**

```
var value = browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('myKey');");
```

**Set value**

```
browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');");
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But this is for retrieval operation not for storing purpose.