# Angular 2 Protractor e2e - localStorage is undefined

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to test the login service using some mock data. Using AuthGuard, secured routes are locked and so upon successful login, it will check the localStorage if there's an authToken.

This is unfortunately failed because Protractor is running in a Node context.

- Failed: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
  ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
  at RESTService.getAuthToken

This is in the protractor.conf.js:

```
beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
},
```

Also, Protractor requires zone-node to run.

In which case, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you also paste your code here to get the localstorage / which is causing the error?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. It's just
    return localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);

Comment: Tnx, but please paste your code, that is used to get the localstorage, so the complete method,  here.

Comment: Which part of the code sorry?

Comment: It's related to this https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/issues/67

Comment: There's an error with Protractor missing zone

Comment: So I had to add require('zone.js/dist/zone-node'); to the protractor.conf.js, onPrepare function, which allows it to run. But it fails because it is now running within Node context.

Comment: It works on normal test except where localStorage call occurs inside the code.

Comment: that was the rest of the method:   getAuthToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localStorage in Protractor test for AngularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960598/accessing-localstorage-in-protractor-test-for-angularjs-application)